# check ftplib response code

Tags: python, exception, ftp, ftplib

I have a python application that's accessing an ftp server.  There are several error cases I'd like to catch in a fashion similar to httplib2:

```
try: 
    urllib2.urlopen("http://google.com")
except urllib2.HTTPError, e: 
    if e.code == 304: 
        #do 304 stuff
    if e.code == 404: 
        #do 404 stuff
    else: 
        pass
```

Does a a construct like this exist in ftplib.err_perm?  I know that could return a code of 500-599 according to the docs but I don't see anything in the docs about how to access that value.  Did I miss something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access error reponse string using `<exception_obj>.args[0]`. It contains strings like `'550 /no-such-dir: No such file or directory'`.

To get error code (only leading three chracters), use `<exception_obj>.args[0][:3]`.

For example:

```
import ftplib
ftp = ftplib.FTP('ftp.hq.nasa.gov')
ftp.login('anonymous', 'user@example.com')
try:
    ftp.cwd('/no-such-dir')
except ftplib.error_perm as e:
    print('Error {}'.format(e.args[0][:3]))
finally:
    ftp.quit()
```

Comment: That works but is there not a getter for the code or a property of the object that just holds the code?

Comment: @Brad, If you're using `python 2.7`, you can use `e.message[:3]` instead of `e.args[0][:3]`. But it's gone in Python 3.x. There's no other property.  [`ftplib.error_perm`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/179a3cf73e47/Lib/ftplib.py#l61) inherits from `ftplib.Error`, `ftplib.Error` inherits from `Exception` .. [`BaseException`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#BaseException) which does not provide any additional attributes/properties.